# Touch/Click area displaced in responsive menu when scrolled down

Tags: android, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

An interesting problem that I have been unable to debug using developer mode in chrome or remote debugging.

The problem appears on smartphones with a screen size that cuts off the responsive menu at the bottom (and hence requires you to scroll down in the menu to get to "Sprache" for example), as in the following screenshot:

[image]

To get the bug to appear:

- Navigate to https://www.a1.digital
- Launch menu on small screen size or in chrome dev tools device
  toolbar
- Scroll down (important)
- Click on a menu item, for example Sprache
- You will instead be taken to the menu item above or below it, in the case of Sprache you will be taken to Login

If you open the responsive menu but do not scroll it, then all menu items work correctly. But as soon as you scroll down the menu items appear displaced.

Tested on Android Chrome, Android Firefox and Android Microsoft Edge, but displays in all three tested browsers.

Here is a video showing first how I load the menu, scroll down and click on Sprache, but it loads the menu item above it which is Login.

Then I navigate back to the home page and load the menu again. This time I do not scroll and I click on Marketplace which loads it correctly.

https://youtu.be/ke-33uzD8h0

Comment: Just tested on Chrome v71.0.3578.98 using Chrome Dev Tools (iphone 4 settings) on a desktop PC and on Chrome v71.0.3578.99 on an Android 7.0 phone and it works without a problem. Could the issue be caused by an extension of yours or something specific to your setup ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I think I found a solution (not sure if it's the best solution though). But first, the problem:

When you click on the navigation, the class `locked` is added to your `.navbar-collapse.collapse`. This happens JUST before the click is registered. `.locked` adds `overflow: hidden` to your navigation, which makes it unscrollable. Now if you already scrolled, it will "jump back" to the top edge and register the click on whichever navigation entry is under the mouse at that point. You can actually see this happen just before the page changes. The solution I found for this is the following CSS:

```
.navbar-collapse.collapse.collapse {
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
    overflow-y: auto !important;
}
```

We use .collapse twice, so it doesn't get overridden. This keeps the scrolling active and should help your case. But this may have other consequences, so test it well. Add a comment if you have questions or other problems with this.

Comment: Allow me to ask stupidly, but could I not remove overflow: hidden from the menu? Is it a must for responsive menus?

Comment: @PartisanEntity that's basically what this CSS does, it overrides the overflow hidden with overflow auto (y) and sets it back to the default. If you can remove the overflow:hidden from the menu that would be the more ideal solution. But I wasn't sure if `.locked` is part of a framework (like bootstrap) and if you can edit it. You could also prevent your menu from being `.locked` on click, depending on how much you can/want to edit in your other code.

Comment: As a test I tried to comment out navbar-collapse.collapse, as well as add "overflow.scroll !important" to it. I also tried your suggestion. In all 3 cases the problem persists. On any device where the height cuts off the menu and where the user has to scroll down to see remaining menu items, the items are displaced and click on x takes you to y instead. Such a weird issue - never seen something like this before.

What's interesting is that if I add background:red to navbar-collapse.collapse then when I view the menu and scroll down then anything that was below

Comment: I think this has something to do with Android, we just tested an older iPhone where the screen size cut off the menu at the bottom and the user is forced to scroll to see lower menu items, and despite scrolling all menu items worked as expected.